# fill the empty space when toggling a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two div left div should be of 30% width and rightdiv should occupy remaining space(70%).

HTML

```
<div class="leftDiv">
        menu
    </div>
    <div class="rightDiv">
        <span id="showdiv" style="float:left;cursor:pointer;">>>></span>content
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.leftDiv{
        float:left;
        height:100% !important;
        width:30%;
        background:orange;
        }
        .rightDiv{
        float:left;
        height:100%;
        background:red;
        }
```

SCRIPT

```
    $(function(){
    var toggle=1;

        $('#showdiv').click( function() {   
        if(toggle==1){
            toggle=0;
            $(".leftDiv").toggle(600,function() {

            }); 
         $('.rightDiv').width('100%');
        }else{
            toggle=1;
            $(".leftDiv").toggle(600,function() {

             });
         $('.rightDiv').width('70%');
        } 


        });

    });
```

My problem is left div is not hideing smoothly i sense rightdiv gets 100% width before rightdiv hides.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: so, don't resize rightDiv until leftDiv is done hiding/showing.

Comment: @kevin i want to show both growth of leftdiv and hide of rightdiv in smooth animation

Comment: @pete i couldn't get what u mean,can u pls give a code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doesn't really understand wich DIV your are trying to show/hide, but you could try this way. You should animate each element in the same time, and not use callback functions.

```
$('.rightDiv').animate({
    width: '100%'
}, 600)
$(".leftDiv").animate({
    width: '0%'
}, 600);
```

See if [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ErH5z/) is what you expected.

**EDIT #1**

http://jsfiddle.net/XXzbm/

**EDIT #2**

add this in the right DIV :

```
position:absolute;
right:0;
```

and remove `float:right`

http://jsfiddle.net/XXzbm/6/

Comment: when the <div id="container" style="width:100%;height:100%;"> is set,the behaviour totally changes

Comment: I tried <div id="container" style="width:100%;height:100%;"> and by adding in css too, and the behaviours doesn't change at all. See the fiddle in the first Edit

Comment: yes the behaviour changes in your fiddle,the animation was smooth when hiding the rightdiv(orange),but when showing it again the  leftdiv(red) moves to nextline and then comes to its position

Comment: ok, it happens in IE, FF, and not Chrome. I'm having a look for a fix.

Comment: So, you can check the Edit 2